# CarrierWave how to store file at given url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I have CarrierWave working fine through the typical ORM setup and upload via form. I would like to figure out how to use CarrierWave outside of the form submission context. For example, when a user registers I would like to grab their gravatar and store it with CarrierWave. Here's what I have, and it does not work:

```
gravatar_url = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/#{Digest::MD5.new.update(current_user.email)}?s=512&d=identicon"

uploader = ImageUploader.new
uploader.store! gravatar_url
```

No error either. I've been looking around the web and have not been able to find a solution.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've had lots of trouble trying to figure out how to get `store!` to work with local file paths. It turns out that `store!` actually takes a file as a parameter, not a string.

For the URL, you'll need to `require 'open-uri'` first, then open the file/url. Something like this should work:

```
require 'open-uri'
gravatar_url = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/#{Digest::MD5.new.update(current_user.email)}?s=512&d=identicon"
tempfile = open(gravatar_url)    

uploader = ImageUploader.new
uploader.store! tempfile
```

The same will work with a file path, but you don't have to require `open-uri` in that case.

Answer (score 46):

in the controller after user sign up (assuming your user image field is called simply 'image')

```
gravatar_url = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/#{Digest::MD5.new.update(current_user.email)}?s=512&d=identicon"
@user.remote_image_url = gravatar_url
@user.save
```

i think this is the best way according to [carrierwave docs](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave#uploading-files-from-a-remote-location) and some searching around.

enjoy!

Comment: This works great. Thanks! I spent a lot of time in figuring out more complex  methods.

Comment: glad i could help! this is a really useful method when importing from social or any service apis.

Comment: I want to use this in the callback before_create because i use devise where i have no controller, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @aisensiy, i hope i understand your problem correctly- you can set the address up, but in order to actually upload the image you'll have to save a record to the db first. try creating a guest model, and after the user is created re-associate or recreate the image. hopefully this should lead you in the right direction:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/393-guest-user-record

Answer (score 19):

Actually you can do this using the built in `remote_{attribute}_url` property if you are using the active record/model helpers (see the CarrierWave railscast for the details). However, I dug around in the source code a bit to see how this actually works and it appears that even if you are not you should be able to use the following:

```
uploader = ImageUploader.new
uploader.download! some_remote_url
uploader.store!
```

Give it a try.

Comment: It seems to be a way safer solution.

Comment: This one best, because with this method we saving file extension.