# Ruby on Rails save images and videos in different fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, feedjira

How to save images and videos in different fields from rss feed

I have enclosure_url and enclosure_type

If this type is image save in picture field

For example:

```
feed = Feedjira::Feed.fetch_and_parse 'http://example.com/feed.xml'

feed.entries.first.enclosure_url # => "http://example.com/d260eb5c"
feed.entries.first.enclosure_type # => "image/jpeg"

feed.entries.last.enclosure_url # => 'https://youtu.be/AnXR-MKhg64'
feed.entries.last.enclosure_type # => "video/x-ms-asf"
```

feed_entry.rb

```
class FeedEntry
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  require 'social_shares'

  field :enclosure_url, type: String
  field :enclosure_type, type: String
  field :video, type: String
  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader

  before_save :media_type
   def media_type
     if self.enclosure_type = /image\//
       self.picture = self.enclosure_url
     else
       self.video = self.enclosure_url
     end
   end

end
```

Comment: are you using paperclip ? what is the attribute and model name you want to save ?

Comment: @SherifElkassaby I updated my question

Comment: unfortunately  i dont get the question more now, so you have the url and the type of the attachment so you can check the extension type then save in the proper location.Can you explain more what is the issue

Comment: @SherifElkassaby how to save in proper location?

Comment: is the feed_entry will have more than 1 attachment ?

Comment: @SherifElkassaby no

Comment: i dont have much experience with carrierwave to know if it valid to save video or photo in the same field .
but you can:
- create another field for video to have two separate fields ( picture and video )
- create a callback after_save to check the  enclosure_type to know to which field u will insert into the attachment
-to save the attachment from url please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/7519455/4958091

Comment: thanks, how to create this attachment with regex?

Comment: i do not know sorry